# Value of type char* cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char"

Tags: c++, char, initialization, entity

I'm new to C++ and I'd like to do simple stuff such as writting to disk the content of a char[]

I'm having hard times doing it.

Here's my code:

```
char x[256],y[256],z[256];

        sprintf( x, "%.2f", pCommandHandling->m_dtHandleInformation[i].Xfrms.translation.x ); //pCommandHandling->m_dtHandleInformation[i].Xfrms.translation.x  is a float struct


        sprintf( y, "%.2f", pCommandHandling->m_dtHandleInformation[i].Xfrms.translation.y ); //pCommandHandling->m_dtHandleInformation[i].Xfrms.translation.y  is a float struct


        sprintf( z, "%.2f", pCommandHandling->m_dtHandleInformation[i].Xfrms.translation.z ); //pCommandHandling->m_dtHandleInformation[i].Xfrms.translation.z  is a float struct

    FILE *tracker_file = fopen("NDI_FiMe.TMP","w");
                char buffer[] = {x,";",y,";",z};
                fwrite(buffer , sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), tracker_file);
                fclose(tracker_file);
```

The problem I'm having is that I get:

IntelliSense: a value of type "char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char"

Comment: What do you want `char buffer[] = {x}` to do?  Make a copy of the array?

Comment: Well, let me modify my example to add more code, is not just x, there are 3 variables. x, y and z

Comment: **Please** make your example a real program that's really giving you that error.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a char array (x) in a list of chars. As the error message says. If you want to copy a char array into another char array see the strcat family of functions.

The next error involves sizeof. It does not compute the length of a string. As you are using it now it will give a 4: the size of the buffer pointer.  There is a strlen function for getting the length of C string.