# A value of type "const char*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"

Tags: c++

I have a code like this but I keep receiving this error :

```
A value of type "const char*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"
```

What is going on?
I have read up on the following threads but have not been able to see any result to my answer as all of them are either from `char` to `char*` or `char*` to `char`:
[Value type const char cannot be used to initialize an entity of type char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030685/value-type-const-char-cannot-be-used-to-initialize-an-entity-of-type-char)
[Value of type char* cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254183/value-of-type-char-cannot-be-used-to-initialize-an-entity-of-type-char)

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 0; //variable x created
    int cars (14);//cars is created as a variable with value 14
    int debt{ -1000 };//debt created with value 1000
    float cash = 2.32;
    double credit = 32.32;
    char a = 'a';//for char you must use a single quote and not double
    char* sandwich = "ham";
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017

Comment: `const char* sandwich = "ham";`

Comment: which part of the error message you don't understand? it means the initialization (i.e. the right side of your expression) has type `const char*` whereas you declared a `char*`. Just modify the declared type as it said

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is conversion from string constant to 'char\*' valid in C but invalid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944784/why-is-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-valid-in-c-but-invalid-in-c)

Comment: This is a beginner question, but it’s not a bad question. The fact that `int` is to `const int` as `char*` is to `char* const`, not `const char*`, is not obvious.

Comment: Just so the OP knows, you should avoid "fixing" it this way. `char *sandwich = (char *)"ham";`  This works only due to backwards compatibility with C and you are throwing away type safety for no reason.

Comment: I fixed this issue in Visual Studio 2019. Right Click Project -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Conformance mode = NO (Default is yes/permissive-). This error appeared in a library so there was no way to modify the code.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That is correct.  Let’s say you had the following code:

```
const char hello[] = "hello, world!";
char* jello = hello; // Not allowed, because:
jello[0] = 'J'; // Undefined behavior!
```

Whoops!  A `const char*` is a non-const pointer to `const char`.  If you assign its value to a non-const `char*`, you’ve lost its `const` property.

A `const` *pointer to* non-const `char` would be a `char* const`, and you can initialize a `char*` from that all day if you want.

You can, if you really want, achieve this with `const_cast<char*>(p)`, and I occasionally have, but it’s usually a sign of a serious design flaw.  If you actually get the compiler to emit instructions to write to the memory aliased by a string constant, you get undefined behavior.  One of the many things that *might* go wrong is that some implementations will store the constant in read-only memory and crash.  Or the same bytes of memory might be re-used for more than one purpose, because after all, we warned you never to change it.

By the way, the rules in C are different.  This is solely for backward-compatibility with early versions of C that did not have the `const` keyword, and you should never write new code that uses a non-const alias to a string constant.

Answer (score 18):

You need to make your string literal type **`const`** because in C++ it is a constant array of `char`, unlike C where it is just an array of `char`. You cannot change a string literal, so making it `const` is preferred in C++ for extra safety. It is the same reason you have to use an explicit cast when going from `const char*` to `char*`. It's still technically "allowed" in C++ since it is allowed in C, which is why it's just a warning. It's still bad practice to do so.  To fix the warning, make it `const`.

```
const char* sandwich = "ham";
```

Comment: Well explained.

Answer (score 1):

Your code (and underlying assumption) is valid `pre C++11 standard`.

---

*String literals* (e.g. "ham") since `C++11` are of type `const char* (or const char[]) if you will` instead of `char *` they used to be. `[Always read specs for breaking changes!!!]`
Hence the warning in VS 2017. Change the compiler version to pre C++11 version and you will be amazed.

This has subtle nuances and can cause frustrating debug sessions

```
// C++11 or later

auto c = "Rowdie"; 
// c has type const char*, can't use c to modify literal
c[0] = 'H'; // illegal - CTE

// -vs- 

char * d = "Rowdie";
d[0] = 'H';
cout << d; // outputs "Howdie"
```

Also another example is auto return type from functions

```
auto get_literal() {
  // ... function code
  return "String Literal";
}

// and using value later
char* lit = get_literal(); // You get same error as const char* cannot be init to char*
```