# Cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'char *' with an lvalue of type 'const char *'

Tags: c++

I have the following:

data.hpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
class Data{

private:
    char* input_filename;
    char* csv_filename;

public:
    Data(const char* in_filename,const char* out_csv="output.csv");
};

#endif /* data_hpp */
```

And `data.cpp`

```
#include "data.hpp"

Data::Data(const char* in_filename,const char* out_csv): input_filename(in_filename), output_csv(out_csv)
{}
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'char *' with an lvalue of type 'const char *'
```

How can I initialize two array of chars that are passed in the constructor?

Comment: Those aren't "arrays of chars", they're "pointers to chars".  Two completely different things.  Just make your member pointers `const` too.

Comment: Change `char* input_filename;` to `std::string input_filename;`.  Same for `csv_filename`.

Comment: @Eljay yeah, that's a better suggestion than mine.

Comment: but why the error?

Comment: @VictorSanchez The member you want to initialize is `csv_filename`, not `output_csv`. The compiler is right to complain (even if in a pretty roundabout way) that it doesn't understand what you are trying to call/initialize.

Comment: @jvd I have to believe that's a typo, because the error message would be different.

Comment: @MarkRansom Deleted comment.

Comment: Very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759558/a-value-of-type-const-char-cannot-be-used-to-initialize-an-entity-of-type-ch) - same problem, different error message.

Answer (score 3):

`char*` is a "pointer to a non-const `char`".

`const char*` is a "pointer to a const `char`".

You can't assign a `const char*` to a `char*`, which is what the compiler is complaining about.  So, you will have to either:

- change the `char*` members to `const char*`:

```cpp
class Data{

private:
    const char* input_filename;
    const char* csv_filename;

public:
    Data(const char* in_filename, const char* out_csv = "output.csv");
};
```

```cpp
#include "data.hpp"

Data::Data(const char* in_filename, const char* out_csv):
    input_filename(in_filename), csv_filename(out_csv)
{}
```

- change the `char*` members to `std::string`:

```cpp
#include <string>

class Data{

private:
    std::string input_filename;
    std::string csv_filename;

public:
    Data(const char* in_filename, const char* out_csv = "output.csv");

    /* you can optionally change the constructor parameters to std::string, too...
    Data(const std::string &in_filename, const std::string &out_csv = "output.csv");
    */
};
```

```cpp
#include "data.hpp"

Data::Data(const char* in_filename, const char* out_csv):
    input_filename(in_filename), csv_filename(out_csv)
{}

/* or:
Data::Data(const std::string &in_filename, const std::string &out_csv):
    input_filename(in_filename), csv_filename(out_csv)
{}
*/
```